# Variations in AppEngine request latency

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to understand the inconsistency in AppEngine's request latency.  Why would the exact same requests called one after another have such variation in response times.
The following log show response times ranging from 53ms to 706ms coming from the same instance and a servlet that makes one call to the datastore api, retrieving a single field:

```
2012-06-21 11:04:03.673 /admin/q/ListingReport/all 200 706ms 11kb 
2012-06-21 11:04:02.205 /admin/q/ListingReport/all 200 53ms 11kb 
2012-06-21 11:03:02.681 /admin/q/ListingReport/all 200 544ms 11kb 
2012-06-21 11:03:01.161 /admin/q/ListingReport/all 200 697ms 11kb 
2012-06-21 11:02:58.603 /admin/q/ListingReport/all 200 54ms 11kb
```

This log shows response times ranging from 8ms to 500ms and is static content:

```
2012-06-21 11:22:12.084 /lib/lst/clientMain.js 304 13ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:12.023 /stdlib/js/jscore/Template.js 304 500ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:12.022 /lib/lst/EventBus.js 304 546ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:12.022 /lib/lst/ClientPoster.js 304 575ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:12.022 /lib/lst/pages/ListingsEditPage.js 304 582ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:12.021 /lib/lst/ClientDataStore.js 304 580ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:12.020 /lib/lst/pages/ListingsAddPhotoPage.js 304 587ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:11.435 /lib/lst/pages/ListingsNewPage.js 304 9ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:11.409 /lib/lst/pages/ListingsPage.js 304 8ms 0kb
2012-06-21 11:22:11.401 /lib/lst/pages/DashboardPage.js 304 8ms 0kb
```

I plan to enable AppStats inorder to see if datastore is causing the latency variations for my API calls, but why would static files be soo different?

Comment: Did you check the log on app engine for instance startups? They are slow.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ Yes, I have checked. My instance start up is around 15 seconds.  So, these are not effected by that.

Comment: Have you tried to make modifications on Pending Latency in "Application Settings"? It works on the queue before the request is handled by the instance

Comment: @MicheleOrsi I'm the only user making requests to this application and I'm waiting for the response to come back before making another, so there should be no pending requests.

Comment: I'm here 10 years later with the same problem. :) No solution found yet.